# How to do cross lagged correlation between two variables (measured multiple times)with multiple cases in R?

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation

I'm a novice for time series. I know that for cross-lagged correlation, the typical example (e.g., CCF in R and SPSS) is one case, two variables, measured multiple times.

But what if I have **multiple cases**. For example, We have:

```
ID  Time    X   Y
1   1   0.138   0.629
1   2   0.389   0.271
1   3   0.127   0.934
1   4   0.871   0.754
2   1   0.242   0.536
2   2   0.572   0.739
2   3   0.140   0.651
2   4   0.326   0.693
3   1   0.169   0.671
3   2   0.127   0.670
3   3   0.038   0.688
3   4   0.030   0.165
...
```

In this example, **each case (identified by ID) is measured 4 times for two variables(X, Y)**, so how can I calculate the cross correlation between X and Y? I checked many documents but didn't find solution yet, so I came here asking for help. 
(R, SPSS are both OK for me)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Look up the split-apply-combine paradigm. With a library like dplyr, you `group_by(id)`, then perform the analysis, so that each `id` is treated separately.  (Applying the group by, the problem reduces to the typical example)

Comment: Thank you. But I checked the group_by() function in dplyr  package, I was still confused how to integrate the group_by function into CCF.

Comment: Something like `dt %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(ccf = CCF(X, Y))` where `CCF` is your cross correlation function?